# Callback function not upgrading graphs

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a dataset and I want to plot some graphs. I created a plotly graph that loads correctly with a callback function where I can select the year I want the data. The dataset loads correctly and there are no missings or errors. But Whenever I try to change the data nothing happens.

my dataset has columns like this
codass Q NF CURS 
240011 1 7  2010
240011 2 5  2010
240012 1 2  2011

I tried starting with a blank graph, and nothing happens. The data is fine cause the initial graph loads correctly it's on the updating procedure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go


FaseIni = pd.read_csv('/Users/Jordi/Documents/Universitat/TFG/tfg/Spyder path/qfaseini18.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf-8')

Q=[1,2]

anys=FaseIni['CURS'].unique()

pv = FaseIni.pivot_table( index=['CODASS'], columns=['Q'], values=['NF'], fill_value=0)

trace1=go.Bar(x=pv.index, y =pv[('NF',1)],name='q1')
trace2=go.Bar(x=pv.index, y =pv[('NF',2)],name='q2')

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([

        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='Anys',
            options= [{'label':'2010' , 'value':2010 },{'label':'2011' , 'value':2011 }],
            value =2010,

                )

        ]),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='notes',
            figure={
                'data':[trace1,trace2]
                        }
)
        ])

])





@app.callback(
    Output('notes','figure'),
    [Input('Anys','value')])

def update_graph(Anys):
    pv2 = FaseIni.loc[FaseIni['CURS'] == Anys]
    pv2 = pv2.pivot_table( index=['CODASS'], columns=['Q'], values=['NF'], 
    fill_value=0)
    trace3=go.Bar(x=pv2.index, y =pv2[('Anys',1)],name='q1')
    trace4=go.Bar(x=pv2.index, y =pv2[('Anys',2)],name='q2')
    return {'data':[trace3,trace4]}
```

The initial graph loads correctly, it just doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem the other day. I'm not sure if this will troubleshoot it because I don't have the csv file to test it but try changing to this:

trace3=go.Bar(x=pv2.index, y =pv2[(**value**,1)],name='q1')

trace4=go.Bar(x=pv2.index, y =pv2[(**value**,2)],name='q2')